# Expected value from a game which gives random numbers from 1 to 100 but limited to 5 rolls

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am trying to solve this probability problem

There is a random number generation machine that gives from 0 to 100 random number, and at each roll you can either take the number as dollars in which case game ends, or roll again but you can roll only 5 times.

So i got the expecation after each roll, which is $E[x] = 50.5$, but can't figure out the optimal algorithm

I have seen the other similar questions like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1977360/expected-value-from-a-game-which-gives-random-numbers-from-1-to-100-with-reducin), but I cant figure out how to do it whithout reducing payoff and with limit

Comment: Can you solve the problem for 2 rolls?

Comment: @Arthur I assume for two the threshold is 50, so roll once, if greater than 50 take, else roll second time

Comment: (Hint: The threshold is actually 50.5.) Cool. What's the expected value if you do that?

Comment: I think its $50.5 + \frac{101}{4} = 75.75$

Comment: Think about it one more time, a little more carefully. What's the probability that you keep the first die, and what's the expected value of the first die under the condition that you keep it?

Comment: its 0.5 probability, and the condition is that number is greater than 50.5, so expectation should be 75.75*0.5=37.875?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with two dice. You keep the first die if it rolls more than $50.5$, and otherwise you roll the second.

You have probability $\frac12$ of rolling over $50.5$ on the first die, and if you do, the expected value on that die is $\frac{151}{2}$.  You have probability $\frac12$ of discarding the first die and try again, with expected value $\frac{101}2$. The expected final result is then $$\frac12\cdot\frac{151}{2}+\frac12\cdot\frac{101}{2}=62$$

If you have three dice, you will keep the first one if it is 63 or better, which means probability $\frac{38}{100}$ and expected value $\frac{163}2$. If the first die is worse than $63$, you try again with expected value $63$ and probability $\frac{62}{100}$. The final expectation for three dice is therefore
$$
\frac{38}{100}\cdot\frac{163}{2} + \frac{62}{100}\cdot63=70.03
$$
Then keep going for dices four and five.

Comment: so for 4 it will be 71 for threshold and $E[x]=\frac{29}{100}*\frac{171}{2} + \frac{70}{100}*71=74.495$
and for 5 dices, 75 for threshold and $E[x]=\frac{25}{100}*\frac{175}{2}+\frac{74}{100}*75=77.375$?

Comment: @Liam Almost. For 4 dice you have $$E[x]=\frac{30}{100}*\frac{171}{2} + \frac{70}{100}*70.03$$instead